# python - How to get rid of useless data in open dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the open dataset found at. Specifically I am using this dataset: http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-100k/u.item. I am attempting to parse the dataset, when I load it into pandas as such:

```
movie_cols = ['movie_id', 'title','release_date','imdb_url']
movies = pd.read_csv('http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-100k/u.item',sep='|',names=movie_cols)
```

When I attempt to run

```
movies.head()
```

It shows this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  need parameter `usecols` for filter `1., 2., 3. and 5.` columns in function [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
movie_cols = ['movie_id', 'title', 'release_date', 'imdb_url']
movies = pd.read_csv('http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-100k/u.item',
                     sep='|',
                     names=movie_cols,   
                     encoding='latin-1', 
                     usecols = [0,1,2,4])
print (movies.head())
   movie_id              title release_date  \
0         1   Toy Story (1995)  01-Jan-1995   
1         2   GoldenEye (1995)  01-Jan-1995   
2         3  Four Rooms (1995)  01-Jan-1995   
3         4  Get Shorty (1995)  01-Jan-1995   
4         5     Copycat (1995)  01-Jan-1995   

                                            imdb_url  
0  http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Toy%20Story%2...  
1  http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?GoldenEye%20(...  
2  http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Four%20Rooms%...  
3  http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Get%20Shorty%...  
4  http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Copycat%20(1995)
```